# Running pre commits, excluding a directory for multiples hooks

Tags: mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to configure pre-commits to avoid the directory `app/test/`

I can exclude it directly on the hook, for exemple avec mypy :

In cmd line :`mypy . --exclude ^app/test/$`

In the pre-commit.yaml file

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    entry: .
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
```

Which is working perfectly fine.

I want to exclude it directly in the pre-commit config (https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-exclude)  because I'm using mutiple hooks

But I cannot get it working. So far I have tried combinaison of things like this in my pre-commit file :

```yaml
exclude : ^app/test/$
repos :
[...]
```

Do you have any ideas on how should I do this ?

---

## Edit 1

Thanks for your answer. I did made a mistake, my entry is `entry: mypy .`.

I also forget `pass_filenames: false` that is on my pre-commit file. I'm not so sure what's it's doing but without it, the exclusion, even as an argument is not working.

So my pre-commit file is looking like this :

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    entry: mypy .
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$", "--ignore-missing-imports"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
    pass_filenames: false
```

Therefore, it might change some of the results you excpected.

To follow your advices, I have changed my hook to : (removing entry)

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$", "--ignore-missing-imports"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
```

It's not working, the error is : `Missing required key : entry`.

For this configuration :

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$", "--ignore-missing-imports"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
    pass_filenames: false
```

It's not working either, the error is the same : `Missing required key : entry`.

Therefore I added the entry key without `.` :

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    entry: mypy
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$", "--ignore-missing-imports"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
```

It's not working but not excluding the directory

And for this last configuration :

```yaml
-   id: mypy
    name: mypy
    entry: mypy
    args: ["--exclude", "^app/test/$", "--ignore-missing-imports"]
    language: python
    types: [python]
    pass_filenames: false
```

It's not working, I have the following error : `Missing target module`

**Note :** I'm not using it yet, but I also want to use the `strict` flag for mypy.

I'm not using configuration for file mypy, and I don't want to use one.

What can I try to avoid overriding entry or args for mypy but still excluding directory, iedally as a global parameter ?

Thanks

---

## Edit 2

Reading the comments, I have forget a part; I want to run my pre-commit in a CI to avoid the famous `--no-verify`

Answer (score 1):

you've broken the `pre-commit` <=> `mypy` integration by setting `entry: .` (which wouldn't even work? I suspect this is not your actual code and you've instead written `args: [.]` which also breaks the integration but in a way that double-lints all of your code)

mypy is a tricky one as well in that it will follow your imports by default -- so you'll need to exclude it from files passed *and* in the mypy configuration

my recommendation:

- don't override `entry` or `args` for mypy -- and if you do don't add `.` to it as it'll double-lint everything and break file filtering
- add your particular module to mypy's configuration file to ignore it

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Actually the best `mypy` config for me was `pass_filenames: false` and directories enumeration in `args`, this prevents some false negatives (when unchanged file refers to one you've modified, errors in it may be not detected otherwise). And just `ignore_errors = true` in mypy config (`tool.mypy.overrides` section in pyproject.toml for desired modules), without even excluding them from checking.

Comment: you're going to have the slowest path always then -- if that's the trade off you want then sure go for it but it's not usually what is desired for a quick check

Comment: And for the actual question - there's no way to exclude directories from all hooks. Could you consider adding such option? For example, I have a directory with patch for boto3, and it is excluded from all hooks to remain as close to original files as possible. Would be nice to exclude it only once instead of repeating. Should I raise a feature ticket on GitHub with this?

Comment: there is -- it's literally what OP tried to use but when you bypass pre-commit's file filtering or use tools which follow files then it does not help you

Comment: Hm, actually `mypy` works quite fast with fine-grained cache. And for (very) big project I have it outside of pre-commit (in Dockerfile as an extra CI step), because on pre-commit it's still too slow and requires too many packages, duplicating half of our requirements, including giant packages like torch.

Comment: Wait, there **is** top-level `exclude`? You just made my day! Idk how I missed it in the docs previously... Obviously it should work only for files when they are destined by pre-commit and not overridden explicitly, it's what I was looking for.

Comment: it's literally linked in the question

Comment: I have updated my question, do you have any advices for me ?

Comment: `repo: local` is "I am intentionally not doing what is recommended and doing so at my own support" so glhf